# intermittent jQuery not defined issue when using cycle2 carousel

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I'm new to magento 2 and trying to get cycle 2 working on a custom theme but getting jQuery not defined error every so often.

Sometime the page will load correctly, then other times will throw the jQuery not defined error in the console.

Here is my requirejs-config.js file

```
var config = {
paths: {
    'foundation': 'js/bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation',
    'owlcarousel': 'js/owl.carousel.min',
    'cycle2': 'js/jquery.cycle2.min',
    'cycle2carousel': 'js/jquery.cycle2.carousel.min',

},
shim: {
    "foundation": ["jquery"],
    "owlcarousel": ["jquery"]
}
```

};

then in the phtml file i have this:

```
<script>

require(["jquery","foundation","owlcarousel","cycle2","cycle2carousel"], function ($) {

    $(document).foundation();

    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();

    $('.home-promo-pods').owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        margin: 30,
        nav: true,
        navText: [
            "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>",
            "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"
        ],
        autoplay: true,
        dots: true,
        responsiveClass: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                margin: 16
            },
            600: {
                items: 3,
                margin: 15
            },
            1000: {
                items: 3
            }
        }
    });

    $('.home-story-pods').owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        margin: 30,
        nav: true,
        navText: [
            "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>",
            "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"
        ],
        autoplay: true,
        dots: true,
        responsiveClass: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                margin: 16
            },
            600: {
                items: 3,
                margin: 15
            },
            1000: {
                items: 3
            }
        }
    });

    $('.home-review-pods').owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        margin: 30,
        nav: true,
        navText: [
            "<i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i>",
            "<i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i>"
        ],
        autoplay: true,
        dots: true,
        responsiveClass: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                margin: 16
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add shim for cycle too

```
shim: {
"cycle2": ["jquery"],
"cycle2carousel": ["jquery"]
}
```

Widget jquery without load via AMD should be add to shim as dependency

Clear cache

```
rm -r var/cache
rm -r pub/static/_requirejs
rm -r pub/static/frontend
magento:static-content:deploy again if not use developer mode
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the shim property in this way:

```
   shim: {
        'cycle2': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        }
    }
```